Save online file directly to Gdrive on GNOME Online Accounts
Already have Google drive mounted on my nautilus through GNOME Online Account panel.
Is there a way to download online file(s) directly into it without save it first on the harddisk?

please explain why that is a problem. At the same time [edit] your question with details about your Linux distro/version

Some research as to whether Google drive supports this is also a good idea.

No. There are reasons why it isn't designed to function that way.
The closest tool I know of that might help you is https://rclone.org/
Good luck!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
